# In DC-DC converters, how can the ripple current affect the circuit's performance?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductor, heat, buck-boost

I have a DC-DC buck boost converter ([TPS55288](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps55288.pdf?ts=1633196641928&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)) that I was planning on using for a project. I'm making a revision to my current heated gloves, and my circuit needs to be as small as possible since the electronics will be stored inside the gloves themselves.

I need the converter to heat up a 5 ohm heating element with a output voltage ranging from 5V to 8V, an input voltage ranging from 8.4V to 6V, with a switching frequency of 750KHz.

I was going to use a [4.7uH inductor](https://www.vishay.com/docs/34316/ihlp-3232dz-01.pdf), but I noticed that my board got uncomfortably hot (around 60 degrees C probably, I didn't measure it) when running it at a 5V output. When I changed to a [1uH inductor](https://www.vishay.com/docs/34104/ihlp-2525cz-01.pdf), the board was a lot cooler (probably around 40 degrees C.) With this in mind, I was thinking of using the 1uH inductor for the sake of thermals.

So I wanted to ask: Why does a lower inductance value generate less heat on my PCB? What are the positive and negative effects of having a lower inductor size with a large current ripple on a static load?

Comment: Do you really need something so fancy for a heating element? You could probably get away with 30Hz and zero inductance. The heater won't care and thermal characteristics smooth out themselves without the need for electrical intervention. Lower inductance = shorter wire = less resistance all other things equal. But lower inductance = higher ripple = higher peaks which should mean more heat due to I^R so it does seem a little strange. at least for a buck. Yours is buck boost though.

Comment: @DKNguyen I needed a small inductor since size is critical for this project. The heating element is going inside a winter glove, and the electronics need to be as small as possible. And the DC-DC converter is needed for voltage output stability.

Comment: 1) It is possible that lower inductance value **by itself** didn't "solve" your thermal issue. Suppose the 4.7 uH inductor had a saturation current that is too low, that will make the converter ineffient and heat up. **If** your 1 uH inductor didn't saturate then that could result in a better efficiency, less power loss and less heating up.

Comment: 2) The ripple **current** could result in a higher riplle **voltage** at the output (depending on the ESR of the output capacitor). Not all loads/circuits care about that. A **heating element** generally doesn't care at all since the heat capacity makes the response slow anyway.

Comment: You are putting almost 13W of heat into a glove? Ouch.

Comment: I agree with @DKNguyen that for a heating element, such a fancy DCDC might be overkill. Why not use a heating element that can generate enough heat even at the lowest voltage. Then use PWM to switch it on/off to regulate the power. Again: the **thermal capacitance** will make the response of the heating element slow so even a low frequency PWM control (say 100 Hz) will be more than fast enough.

Comment: *The heating element is going inside a winter glove, and the electronics need to be as small as possible. And the DC-DC converter is needed for voltage output stability* That is **CRITICAL info** which you should add in your question. *And the DC-DC converter is needed for voltage output stability* If your load is **only** the heating element: then you don't need voltage stability. But feel free to prove me wrong. I would be more worried about certain spots **overheating** and burning a user's hands.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie My project includes a thermistor that will monitor the glove temperature using an microcontroller. I don't believe the overheating aspect is of concern since I've tested this material before that I'm using for the heating element, and haven't encounter any issues.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie What I meant by "voltage output stability" is that I want the voltage output to stay consistent with the change in input voltage. I don't want an 8V output voltage to drop to 6V when the batteries are dying. Which is why I'm using a DC-DC converter.

Comment: @Jay The solution to that is use less resistance so more  heat is produced with less voltage and throttle back on the duty cycle when the battery is full, not step it up because it's just a heating element. And use zero inductance because the heating element isn't picky. You can outright pulse power to it it but thermal mass keeps the temperature smooth.

Comment: *I don't want an 8V output voltage to drop to 6V when the batteries are dying. Which is why I'm using a DC-DC converter* I'm still not convinced. I would use PWM to control the heating element. Design the heating element such that at 6 V you still get enough heat. Then use PWM to control the power to the heating element. Control the PWM form the thermistor. That's really **much simpler** than using a DCDC. You don't need that DCDC, it only complicates things, it is overkill. You have to design in a "more smart" way.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Hmm. Maybe it's simpler, but I wasn't intending on making any design changes since this was going to be the final design (unless there was some critical flaw). The boards I have for this project have already been ordered and assembled.

Comment: *The boards I have for this project have already been ordered and assembled.* That tells us something about the experience level of all those that are involved. Realize that if you work at a company and design-in a € 6 DCDC chip which actually is not needed, you have some explaining to do.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Except that I didn't care about the cost for this project since the only person involved is me, and this was a hobbyist based project. It would be a different story for work, but I wanted to do this as a learning experience.

Comment: VOTES TO CLOSE: It would be extremely helpful if VTC reasons were known. There seems to be a clear requirement here. Load, Vin ranhe, specific inductors, specific IC, specific problem. If other is needed please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For heating, all you need is a resistive element that will generate enough heat at minimum input voltage, and PWM to control the average power. The PWM doesn't need to be fast, only quicker than the thermal time constant of the load, even the Hz range would be quick enough for a glove heater.

In any design, the smallest, cheapest and most reliable components are the ones you don't fit, because you don't need them. This is the most important learning experience to take from this design. You don't need the inductor, or a fancy high frequency DC-DC chip.

Comment: To add to that: what Neil_UK means is that you don't need an inductor at all, nor the output capacitor, nor the flyback diode. All you need is a MOSFET. Easy!